# Match numeric substring which is preceded or followed by one of two specific substrings

Tags: php, regex, validation, text-extraction, alternation

I have a program that selects an amount from the chain that has `Kč` or `CZK` behind it. How do I edit an expression ( pattern) to check if `Kč` or `CZK` is in front of a number? See string1 and string2:

```
$string='Rohlík 4,99 Kč 51235';
//$string1='Rohlík CZK 4,99 51235';
//$string2='Rohlík Kč4,99 51235';

$replace = [' ', '.'];

$string = str_replace($replace,"",$string);

$string = str_replace(',',".",$string);


/*Change?*/

$pattern = '/[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*[Kč,CZK]/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches); // => 4.99 Kč
$string = $matches;

$pattern = '/[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*/';
preg_match($pattern, $string[0], $matches);

$price = $matches[0];
print_r($price); // => 4.99
```

Comment: Non-capturing group: `(?: )` and alternation: `|` https://www.debuggex.com/r/RqjVlY2tm3ym8HYt

Comment: `[Kč,CZK]`matches one of the character inside, not the word, try: `(Kč|CZK)` instead. It matches EITHER `Kč` or `CZK`.

Comment: Characters listed inside of a "character class" should never be repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use logical grouping in your pattern to match the label which may come before or after the targeted number (replacing the comma with a dot can be done after this step).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lTKSD))

```
$strings = [
    'Rohlík 4,99 Kč 51235',
    'Rohlík CZK 4,99 51235',
    'Rohlík Kč4,99 51235',
    'Rohlík foo4,99 51235'
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    var_export(
        preg_match('/\b(?:(?:Kč|CZK) ?\K\d+(?:,\d+)?|\d+(?:,\d+)?(?= ?(?:Kč|CZK)))\b/u', $string, $m)
        ? $m[0]
        : 'not found'
    );
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
'4,99'
'4,99'
'4,99'
'not found'
```

Pattern Breakdown:

```
/                     #starting pattern delimiter
  \b                  #word boundary to guarantee matching the whole label
  (?:                 #start non-capturing group 1
    (?:Kč|CZK) ?      #non-capturing group 2 requiring one of two labels, optionally followed by a space
    \K                #forget all previously matched characters
    \d+(?:,\d+)?      #match the targeted integer/float value with comma as decimal placeholder
    |                 #OR
    \d+(?:,\d+)?      #match the targeted integer/float value with comma as decimal placeholder
    (?= ?(?:Kč|CZK))  #lookahead to for optional space followed by one of the two labels
  )                   #close non-capturing group 1
  \b                  #word boundary to guarantee matching the whole label
/                     #ending pattern delimiter
u                     #unicode/multi-byte flag
```

Comment: You were right about my post - i deleted it. You should allow comma or period and possible spaces before and after the digits.

Comment: My pattern does allow optional spaces before and after the digits.  The sample input from the OP does not include floats using dots.  I am assuming this is their preferred output format rather than a way of stabilizing the input.  If dots are possible in the input, then `,` can be changed to `[,.]`.

Comment: True that. And with `i` for case insensitive he should be fine.

Comment: Again, the sample input does not indicate that a case-insensitive flag is called for.  It might be, but only the OP knows this.